# Map with same key when fetched shows all related to that key

Tags: java, scala, dictionary, hashmap

I want to do something like this:

```
1 -> imran
2 -> ajmal
3 -> habib
4 -> saurab
4 -> tendulkar
```

If I use `get(1)` I get

`imran`

Now if I use `get(4)` I should get

```
saurab
tendulkar
```

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Would it be feasible for you to simply have a `Map[Int, Vector[String]]` or perhaps even more simply a `Vector[Vector[String]]`?

Comment: yes @user7 it is relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So fir any one key, you want to return more than one or more objects in the result.  One of more objects implies a List.

So you could have :

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<>();

void add(Integer key, String value) {

    List<String> list = myMap.get(key);

    If (list==null) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        myMap.put(key, list);
    }
    list.add(value);
}
```